# AVFormat lib avformat_free_context

Tags: c, libavformat

i try this code to get duration of a media file:

```
AVFormatContext* pFormatCtx = NULL;
avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, filename.c_str(), NULL, NULL);

if (pFormatCtx != 0) {
    avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL);

    int64_t media_duration = pFormatCtx->duration;
    duration = media_duration/AV_TIME_BASE;

    avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);
    avformat_free_context(pFormatCtx);
}
```

The problem is if i call avformat_free_context() the app die, if i comment out the line the program works, but i prefer to avoid memory leak.

PS: i call av_register_all() when the program start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `avformat_close_input` will free the `AVFormatContext` after it close it. That is why you should send `pFormatCtx` by pointer.

So you don't need to call `avformat_free_context` as it is already called by `avformat_close_input` and no need to worry about memory leaks.

See the documentation for [`avformat_close_input`](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/libavformat_2utils_8c_source.html#l04165) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

This function is working in my project, try this.

---

```
 *
 * @param input - the absolute path to file
 * @returns the duration of file in seconds
 *
 */
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_ffmpegjni_videoprocessinglibrary_VideoProcessing_getDuration(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                      jobject instance,
                                                                      jstring input_) {
    av_register_all();
    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
    if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, jStr2str(env, input_), NULL, NULL) < 0) {
        throwException(env, "Could not open input file");
        return 0;
    }


    if (avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL) < 0) {
        throwException(env, "Failed to retrieve input stream information");
        return 0;
    }

    int64_t duration = pFormatCtx->duration;

    avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);
    avformat_free_context(pFormatCtx);
    return (jint) (duration / AV_TIME_BASE);
}
```